# Joining on UDFs in Snowflake

Tags: user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

After creating some UDFs, the following query works:

```
    SELECT
        rsp.id
    FROM TABLE(UDF_1('2019-04-18 12:00:00'::timestamp_ltz)) AS rsp
```

However, this query:

```
    SELECT
        rsp.id
    FROM TABLE(UDF_1('2019-04-18 12:00:00'::timestamp_ltz)) AS rsp
    JOIN TABLE(UDF_2('2019-04-18 12:00:00'::timestamp_ltz)) AS rasp ON 
        rsp.id = rasp.id AND
        rsp.timestamp = rasp.start;
```

Gives me:

`SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 8 invalid identifier 'RSP.ID'`

If the first query did not work, I would understand. However, since the first query *does* work, why I am then told `RSP.ID` is invalid?

Comment: Looks like a possible bug / limitation. Please consider raising this with Snowflake support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution:

```
    SELECT
        rsp.id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE(UDF_1('2019-04-18 12:00:00'::timestamp_ltz))) AS rsp
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(UDF_2('2019-04-18 12:00:00'::timestamp_ltz))) AS rasp ON 
        rsp.id = rasp.id AND
        rsp.timestamp = rasp.start;
```

works. We surmised that the `JOINs` were happening before the execution of the function, thus there was "nothing" to `JOIN` on.

I am sure this can be more efficient by selecting only the rows I want oppose to `*`, but the above worked for me.